# Read micro sd card on PI zero

Tags: pi-zero, data-transfer

I have been searching for hours for a way to connect my pi to a computer and read/write data to the micro sd card. Is there any way to do this, and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you have to have SD with OS of your choice on it installed first and Zero running. Add USB keyboard and or optional mouse to the Zero USB port.

Then you will need an additional hardware (USB) to "connect remotely" to Zero - assuming  plain Zero, not W option.